# How to setup miracast Ubuntu 18?

Tags: screencast

How can I setup miracast on Ubuntu 18? I found a [github page](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) for it but it wasn't very beginner friendly. Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: ...and where is the link to that page?

Comment: added link @mikewhatever